# postgres default values are applying on update, not just at create

Tags: postgresql, default-value, upsert

**In the process of writing this question, I found the answer and will post it below.  If there are already duplicates of this question, please notify me and I will remove it, I was unable to find any.**

I've got two columns tracking changes made to a table in postgres:

```
created_at timestamp default now()
updated_at timestamp
```

the updated_at column is being updated by a trigger:

```
united_states_congress=> \d congressional_bill_summaries;
                                      Table "public.congressional_bill_summaries"
   Column    |            Type             |                                 Modifiers                                 
-------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | bigint                      | not null default nextval('congressional_bill_summaries_id_seq'::regclass)
 text        | text                        | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone | 
 bill_kid    | integer                     | not null
 date        | date                        | not null
 description | character varying(255)      | not null
 text_hash   | uuid                        | 
Indexes:
    "congressional_bill_summaries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "congressional_bill_summaries_bill_kid_date_description_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (bill_kid, date, description)
Triggers:
    hash_all_the_things BEFORE INSERT ON congressional_bill_summaries FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE hash_this_foo()
    update_iz_yoo BEFORE UPDATE ON congressional_bill_summaries FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_iz_now()
```

as is one other column of the table, text_hash

My expected behavior is that when a line is first inserted, the created_at column will update to default value (which I understand to be the time at which the current transaction began, not the time of the specific query).

My expected behavior is that when a line is updated, the updated_at line will be updated by this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_iz_now()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = now();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

but that created_at will remain unchanged, because a value is already in the column, so it should not override with the default.

created_at is initially functioning correctly:

```
united_states_congress=> select created_at, updated_at from congressional_bill_actions limit 5;
         created_at         | updated_at 
----------------------------+------------
 2017-01-28 00:08:11.238773 | 
 2017-01-28 00:08:11.255533 | 
 2017-01-28 00:08:15.036168 | 
 2017-01-28 00:08:15.047991 | 
 2017-01-28 00:08:15.071715 | 
(5 rows)
```

But then when a line is updated, created_at is being changed to match the insert value of updated_at, leaving me with:

```
united_states_congress=> select created_at, updated_at from congressional_bill_actions where updated_at is not null limit 5;
         created_at         |         updated_at         
----------------------------+----------------------------
 2017-01-28 07:55:34.078783 | 2017-01-28 07:55:34.078783
 2017-02-01 18:47:50.673996 | 2017-02-01 18:47:50.673996
 2017-02-02 14:50:33.066341 | 2017-02-02 14:50:33.066341
 2017-02-02 14:50:33.083343 | 2017-02-02 14:50:33.083343
 2017-02-03 13:58:34.950716 | 2017-02-03 13:58:34.950716
(5 rows)
```

I have been all over the internet trying to figure this one out, but the internet keeps helpfully routing me to questions about "how to create default values" and "how to make triggers."

This obviously must be a usage problem somewhere on my end, but I'm having trouble identifying it.  Just in case, here is the other trigger being run on the table (on insert):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.hash_this_foo()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  NEW.text_hash = md5(NEW.text)::uuid;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

**In the process of writing this question, I found the answer and will post it below.  If there are already duplicates of this question, please notify me and I will remove it, I was unable to find any.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem here was my **UPSERT** handling, during which the schema of the table was being pulled in, resulting in the dynamic creation of queries that included lines like this:

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT congressional_bill_actions_bill_kid_date_action_actor_key DO UPDATE SET created_at = EXCLUDED.created_at,
```

because created_at was being set automatically to the EXCLUDED.created_at, this was causing the default value to overwrite the existing one precisely because I was instructing it to do so.

So when writing UPSERT handlers, this is something to be aware of, it would seem.

(Note: the way to avoid this is simply not to pull in any columns where column_default is not null.)